# MySQL Database INNER Joins - Query Help

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is make a query so I can make the fights table more readable.
So Fighter 1 would pull the id of 1 from the fighters table, and Fighter 2 would do the same thing.  Winner is either 0, 1, 2.  Zero means it is a draw, and then 1 means that Fighter 1 won and 2 means that fighter 2 won.

The query I tried so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) 'Fighter 1', 
       CONCAT(victory_method.name, ' (', method_notes, ')') 'Victory' 
  FROM fights 
  JOIN fighters ON fights.fighter1_id = fighters.id
  JOIN victory_method ON fights.victory_method_id = victory_method.id
```

[image]

Now that is a good start, but what I need is to figure out how to get Fighter 2 listed on there as well, and then also the Winner, either if it was a Draw or fighter 1 or 2 who won.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inner Join fighters table again, using alias `as`

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(fo.first_name, ' ', fo.last_name, if (fights.winner=1, "Winner", "Loser")) 'Fighter 1', 
CONCAT(ft.first_name, ' ', ft.last_name, if (fights.winner=2, "Winner", "Loser")) 'Fighter 2', 
CONCAT(victory_method.name, ' (', method_notes, ')') 'Victory' 
FROM fights 
INNER JOIN fighters as fo ON fights.fighter1_id = fo.id
INNER JOIN fighters as ft ON fights.fighter2_id = ft.id
INNER JOIN victory_method ON fights.victory_method_id = victory_method.id
```

Comment: I modified the answer, make sure to use alias, you can't join/select identical field because mysql don't know which one you are talking about.

Comment: remove fighers. modfied answer

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfect. So for winners, I added ", Winner" to the SELECT so it says the winner is 1. how do I make it say Winner Anderson Silver because it sees Anderson Silva is fighter 1?

Comment: you can use IF or JOIN subquery, see modified answer

Comment: Thanks that worked but actually I think it would be better just to add a new view for "Winner" and just display "Winner Name" for reporting purposes, right?  Instead of just adding Winner and Loser to their name?  BTW it's actually giving the wrong winner and loser, it should be swapped.